# INDEX formula in Excel, Top 10, repeats previous value

Tags: excel, excel-formula, formula, excel-2016

I am looking through a table with data for top 10 values. I am doing it with formula:

`=LARGE($R$2:$R$26,U13)`

This formula is in the column `V`.

[image]

Tha values are taken over from this table:

[image]

In column `W` I am trying to identify, which exactly country has one of those top 10 values. I am doing it with formula:

`=INDEX($I$2:$I$26,MATCH(V13,$R$2:$R$26,0))`

My problem is as follows. If the top ten value for 2 countries is the same (as in case 9 and 10 at the bottom of my table, where 2 countries have the value 39), my `INDEX` formula repeats the first country found in both rows.

E.g., there should be Nigeria with the Rank 10, because it has also the value 39.

I think, I am doing something wrong, am I?

Comment: Give them different ranks?

Comment: @SJR sorry, I didn't quite get it. I have edited my post, so that I hope it is easier now to understand where the values for ranking are taken from.

Comment: If you have the data on which the ranks are based you can calculate unique ranks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this formula in cell W4:

```
=IF(V3=V4,INDEX(INDIRECT("I"&MATCH(W3,I:I,0)+1&":I26"),MATCH(V4,INDIRECT("R"&MATCH(W3,I:I,0)+1&":R26"),0)),INDEX($I$2:$I$26,MATCH(V4,$R$2:$R$26,0)))
```

The formula checks if the previous country has the same score of the actual one. In such case, it search for the previous country in the list and redefine the range to be seached for the score. This way even a perfect tie in the whole list will produce a list of unique countries.

You formula didn't solve your problem because the INDEX function search for the first occurence of the value that is searched. It doesn't consider if in another cell you have already run another INDEX. By redefining the range to be seached according to the previous result, you will just cut out the first (or second, third, or whatever) occurence of the value you are searching (as well some others values you don't care of).

Exploding the formula we obtain this:

```
=IF(V3=V4,                                    'Checks for a tie
    '---------------------------------------------If it's a tie
    INDEX(                                       'Use a index function to pick the result
          INDIRECT(                                 'Use an indirect function to define the range to be searched
                   "I"&                                'State the column of the range to be searched
                   MATCH(W3,I:I,0)+1&                  'Use a match function to find the previous occurence of the score whithin the column of the range to be searched and add 1 to it to cut out that value (and any previous one)
                   ":I26"                              'State the closing cell of the range to be searched
                  ),
          MATCH(                                    'Use a match function to determine in what row of the defined range the score is occuring
                V4,                                    'The value to be searched
                INDIRECT(                              'Use an indirect function to define the range to be searched
                         "R"&                             'State the column of the range to be searched
                         MATCH(W3,I:I,0)+1&               'Use a match function to find the previous occurence of the score whithin the column of the range to be searched and add 1 to it to cut out that value (and any previous one)
                         ":R26"                           'State the closing cell of the range to be searched
                        ),
                0                                         'Specify that you want the the exact occurence
               )
         ),
    '---------------------------------------------If it's not a tie
    INDEX(                                       'Use a index function to pick the result
          $I$2:$I$26,                               'State the range to be searched
          MATCH(                                    'Use a match function to determine in what row of the range the score is occuring
                V4,                                    'The value to be searched
                $R$2:$R$26,                            'State the range to be searched
                0                                      'Specify that you want the the exact occurence
               )
         )

   )
```

Comment: aaahhh!!! Magician among us!!! Thank you so much for the clearest explanation I ever received!